# Does Blender offer network rendering on a LAN

Tags: rendering, network

Does Blender offer network rendering on a LAN? If so, where are the docs to set this up?. I saw something on setting up a Primitive Render Farm, but no docs as to how this is setup.

Comment: https://cgcookie.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-renderfarm/

Comment: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Render/Cycles/Network_Render

Comment: Crowd render will give you vs 2.2 which is good but linked materials have some difficulties. v2.6 is 4$ per month and most probably solves lots of issues in previous version. V 2.2 is too old and buggy. At least they could give v2.5 to the community.

Comment: You can check the available addons for network rendering, for example BlendNet allows to render in cloud (GCP/AWS) or using your own resources. Check the video here: https://youtu.be/PBa5u7w0FXo

Comment: There is an opensource project BlendNet to simplify both local rendering (on your own resources) and to automate the cloud (AWS/GCP/...) deployments for rendering. Check this out: https://youtu.be/PBa5u7w0FXo

Answer (score 3):

There is no accepted, included, out-of-the-box way right now.  It's on the roadmap of features for them to add, but they haven't reached that feature yet.

Not to say you can't do it, though.  It will just involve custom scripts, python scripts, and some fiddling around to get it going.  Google "Blender network rendering", "Blender distributed rendering", and "Blender render farm" for some ideas.  Without more details about your situation, I can't really recommend anything more specific.

Comment: Also, lookup "Flamenco" on the Blender Cloud. This is the tool that Blender Institute uses to manage their own render jobs.

Comment: ok
have  you used or know anybody who has used crowd render on blender version 2.79 B ?

Comment: I wonder if crow render is dead. I checked out their webpage, they still talk about only supporting 2.79, they announced in 2018 that they would port it over to 2.8, looks like this never happened.